# Data from drop down not deleting from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here's the HTML and PHP mixed. I didn't separate them coz the  tag was being populated by php.

```
    <form method="post">
    <select name="Select User" value="Select User">
    <?php
    $sth = $conn->prepare('Select username From users');
    $sth->execute();
    $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
    foreach ($data as $row ){
        if($row['username']!="")
    echo " <option id=\"Select_user\" name=\"Select_user\" value=\"Select_user\">".$row['username']."</option>";
    }
    ?>

    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"</input>

    <?php
           if(! empty($_POST['Select_user']))
           {
            $del_user=$_POST['Select_user'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username=:del";
            $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute(array(':del'=>$del_user));
           }

    ?>
```

The drop-down is fetching the data correctly, but the delete is not happening. Why?

Comment: echo your query and see .

Comment: What do i see in that?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set proper data in option values which will be posted in php, Selected option value will be posted so as you want user name in $_POST so set user name in option value :

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="user_selection">

    <?php
        $sth = $conn->prepare('Select username From users');
        $sth->execute();


   $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
    foreach ($data as $row ){
        if($row['username']!="")
        echo '<option id="Select_user" name="Select_user" value="'.$row["username"].'">'.$row["username"].'</option>';
    }
    ?>

    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"</input>

    <?php
           if(! empty($_POST['user_selection'])) // access element by its name
           {
            $del_user=$_POST['user_selectio'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username=:del";
            $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute(array(':del'=>$del_user));
           }

    ?>
```

Comment: The drop down is showing the correct values. I'm unable to delete the values from the delete button.

Comment: Isn't name of the element 'username' and not 'user_selection'?

Comment: i have just changed it here for your understanding

Comment: Didn't work. What else? Also, what changes have you done that you're suggesting me? My `<options>` statement is already correct.